Users still cannot delete files owned by root, even with 777 permissions... with NO stickybit on Samba
We have a home server, and I'm trying to figure out permissions. I usually work on the web, so doing home server is new to me, and I have never had this issue before....
We have: Root, Bob, and Cait as users.
We have directories by default are 777. (drwxrwxrw) Owner is root.
The files by default are 666. (-rw-rw-rw-) Owner is root.
Things seem to work as anticipated in command line, but windows explorer in Samba it is not.
I know that permissions 666 can't delete or move when they're not the owner, so for sake of sanity, we tried 777 and still can't delete.
Users Bob and Cait can only read and write... so they can afaik ALWAYS copy something, but SOMETIMES can move and delete stuff, but not always? (I think only if they are the owner instead of root)
Id imagine something like rwxrwxr-- would work, but... even when I do 777.... They still cannot delete, but CAN edit...
Cait and Bob are definitely in "groupwithfullaccess" group.
For example, the file we set to 777 to test is:
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root
—rwxrwxrwx 1 root OURSERVER\groupwithfullaccess textfile.txt

When we try to delete we get:
"You need permission to perform this action
You require permission from Unix User\root to make changes to this file
textfile.txt
Type: Text Document
Size: 96 bytes
Date modified: 2024-08-05 12:29 PM
Try Again
Cancel"
The only way we can delete files is to be logged in as root.
I would imagine this would only be the case when there is a "t" (sticky bit) at the end, to denote "ONLY OWNER CAN DO THIS", however, there is very much no "t"s anywhere on our files.
UPDATE: The commands work fine within command prompt... however it is in File Explorer when things are breaking! We're using samba for our windows file management where things are breaking? We added unix extensions = yes to our settings and still no dice. So it's been narrowed down a bit!
It's only when accessing it over smb, both windows and another linux vm, that I'm getting permission denied moving the files.
How2fix?
Thanks

To delete a file you need write permission for the directory that contains the file, because removing the file will modify the directory, not the data of the file itself.

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Run ls -l on the directory and the file, and [edit] your post to include the exact command and the output in your post. What OS are you on? What filesystem is the directory on?

Alright, so an update - the commands work fine within command prompt... however it is in samba windows file management where things are breaking. We added unix extensions = yes to our settings and still no dice.
So it's been narrowed down a bit!

Please post your samba config in your question. We'll need to see Global and the relevant share section(s)

VTC because still missing necessary detail

I’m voting to close as “Needs details or clarity”, partly for the lack of requested information (OS, output from ls -la, Samba config), but partly because I simply do not understand the OP’s situation.   (1) Apparently the problem is occurring in Windows (what version?), but “The commands (what commands??) work fine within command prompt” but not in Windows/File Explorer.  That makes me believe that the problem is in Windows.   (2) “The only way we can delete files is to be logged in as root.”  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  Where is this happening?  Are you saying that non-root users Bob and Cait cannot delete files on the Unix/Linux file server?  Or are you logging in as root on Windows?  (WSL?)   (3) There’s an intriguing statement about “accessing it over smb” (i.e., Samba?) and “another linux vm”, that is begging to be clarified.  … … … … … … … … …  … … … … … … … … …  But the bottom line is that the OP was last seen 2 months ago, so we aren’t going to get any clarification.
